# Prove that any functor $F : \mathcal C \to \text{Sets}$ where $\mathcal C$ is small is a colimit of representable functors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, representable-functor

> Prove that for any small category $\mathcal C$ and any functor $F:\mathcal C^\text{op}\to\textbf{Set}$, $F$ can be written as a colimit of representable functors $h_x=\text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(-,x)$.

I am aware that there is already [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736224/colimits-of-representable-functors). However, I am not sure if I understand Maclane's notation and terminology. Furthermore, his question was for covariant functors, while my questions is for contravariant functors. So please consider this question as a new question.

Let $\hat{X}$ denote $\text{Mor(-,X)}$ and for $f: X \to Y$ let $\hat{f}$ denote the map $f \circ -$ from $\hat{X}$ to $\hat{Y}$. I am told that we can consider the functor $G: I \to \textbf{Set}^{\mathcal C^{op}}$ where the objects of the category $I$ consists of the pairs $(X, \alpha: \text{Hom}(-,X) \implies F)$ where $X$ is any object in $Obj(\mathcal C)$ and $\alpha$ is any natural transformation between $\text{Hom}(-,X)$ and $F$, and the morphisms in $I$ are morphisms $f: X \to Y$ in $\mathcal C$ such that the following induced diagram commutes (in case the graph shows weirdly, the relation should be $\alpha = \beta \circ \hat{f}$ where $\alpha: \hat{X} \to F, \beta: \hat{Y} \to F, \hat{f}: \hat{X} \to \hat{Y}$:

[
\begin{array}{c}
    \hat{X} \\
    \downarrow \alpha \quad \downarrow \hat{f} \\
    \hat{Y} \quad \xrightarrow{\beta} \quad F
\end{array}
]

Since the category of presheaves on $\mathcal C$ is complete and cocomplete, we know that the colimit of $G$ exists. I have shown that there is a unique morphism between from $\text{colim} G$ to $F$, and what remains to show is that there is a uniuqe morphism from $F$ to $\text{colim} G$, and that the composition of the two morphisms is in fact identity on $F$ or identity on $\text{colim} G$. So suppose that $H$ is a functor from $\mathcal C^{op}$ to $\textbf{Sets}$ such that for any morphism $f : X \to Y$ in $\mathcal C$ we have that $\delta_X = \delta_Y \circ \hat{f}$ where $\delta_X, \delta_Y$ are morphisms of our cone with object $H$ in $\textbf{Sets}^{\mathcal C^{op}}$. By Yoneda's lemma, there is a concrete object $a_X, a_Y \in H(X)$ that uniquely represents $\delta_X$ and $\delta_Y$, respectively. However, I am stuck after here. What do I do?

Comment: There's no difference between the covariant and contravariant cases, you just replace $C$ with $C^{op}$ to translate between one and the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to go into details here since these can be found in many places. I just present the idea and some sense of how you can find the idea for yourself. Basically, *you do the only thing you can do*, which generally is what works in elementary category theory.

---

Rather than try to say, $\varinjlim G$ exists for abstract reasons and we should figure out whether or not $\varinjlim G\cong F$, let's just directly witness a cocone $\lambda_i:G(i)\to F$ and show  this cocone is universal.

So, the object "$i$" is really just a pair $(X,\alpha)$ where $X$ is an object of $\mathsf{C}$ and $\alpha$ is an element of $F(X)$ (or a natural transformation $\hat{X}\implies F$, there is no real difference) and we want to find some arrow $\lambda:\hat{X}\to F$ in the presheaf category... but we are already given the natural transformation $\alpha$ so of course we should choose $\lambda=\alpha:\hat{X}\to F$.

Is this a cocone? Yes, by an easy check. Is it universal? If $H$ also has some $\mu_{(X,\alpha)}:\hat{X}\to H$, these correspond to elements $\mu'_{X,\alpha}$ of $H(X)$ and we want to find a natural transformation $F\to H$ and show this is unique in a certain sense. Well, that means giving a function, for every $X$, $F(X)\to G(X)$. Ok, well I have been given my elements $\alpha\in F(X)$ ($\sim$ maps $\hat{X}\to F$) and I've also been given my elements $\mu'_{X,\alpha}\in H(X)$... it stands to reason I should be mapping $\alpha\mapsto\mu'_{X,\alpha}$. *I have literally no other information about the elements of $H(X)$*, so this is basically the only reasonable choice.

Then you can check this really is well-defined and a natural transformation, and further check it turns the cocone to $F$ into the cocone to $H$ and is also unique in this respect. I leave those to you.